# Python calculator script with functions and lists

Tags: python, list, function, loops

I am trying to create a simple python calculator with inputs as lists and functions defining the operations that can be performed.

I am having trouble getting my functions to return the value after they have returned.

The program is supposed to get numbers in the form of a list and then pass them into the while loop in the main part of the program. The user can perform as many operations as they want before the program quits.

Please let me know what my error is or if I need to add anything.

```
def display_menu():
    print("Please Choose an option")
    print("1. Add (+)")
    print("2. Subtract (-)")
    print("3. Multiply (*)")
    print("4. Divide (/)")
    print("q to quit")

def addition():
    numlist = input("please enter at least 2 numbers to be operated on.").split()
    numlist = [float(num) for num in numlist]
    num1 = numlist[0]
    del numlist[0]
    for num in numlist:
        num1 = num1 + num
    return num1   

def subtraction():  
    numlist = input("please enter at least 2 numbers to be operated on.").split()
    numlist = [float(num) for num in numlist]
    num1 = numlist[0]
    del numlist[0]
    for num in numlist:
        num1 = num1 - num
    return num1

def multiply():   
    numlist = input("please enter at least 2 numbers to be operated on.").split()
    numlist = [float(num) for num in numlist]
    num1 = numlist[0]
    del numlist[0]
    for num in numlist:
        num1 = num1 * num
    return num1

def division():   
    numlist = input("please enter at least 2 numbers to be operated on.").split()
    numlist = [float(num) for num in numlist]
    num1 = numlist[0]
    del numlist[0]
    for num in numlist:
        num1 = num1 * num
    return num1

displ_menu()

operator = input("Please enter an operator: ")

while operator != "q":

    if operator == "+":
        addition()
    elif operator == "-":
        subtraction()
    elif operator == "*":
        multiply()
    else:
        division()
    displ_menu()
    operator = input("please enter an operator")    
print("Closing calculator")
```

Comment: The functions seem to be returning the result just fine. You're just not doing anything with the returned value.

Comment: Use `print(addition())` and similar for all the other operators.

Comment: All your functions start by asking for numbers and converting them to a list. Wouldn't it make more sense to do that in one place, like the main loop, and pass the list as an argument to the function that performs the operation?